# How to automatically create MySQL view with Loopback

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, loopbackjs

I've recently become aware of Loopback and its impressive capabilities. One question I have is regarding data and model migration. I'm absolutely positive it's possible to do this, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Is there a way to write a boot script file within loopback to make it a) check to see if a view exists in MySQL and b) if not, create the view?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Loopback framework you can execute any native command where ever you want.
you must have a model like `appPost` to run commands and attach this model to a mysql datasouce :

### server/server.js

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  ....

  app.models.appPost.dataSource.connector.execute('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ...', null, function (err,response) {
    console.log(response);
  });

  ....
}
```

see Details here : https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Executing+native+SQL